# toUniquePtr implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, c++14, unique-ptr

I work alot with Windows API. everytime I get some sort of OS resource (like a handle. registry key, socket etc.) I wrap it manually with some sort of `unique_ptr<HandleType,SomeDeleter>` in order to deal with proper closing of that handle.

I try to create a lightwight `toUniquePtr` function which get a handle and a closing function and automatically creates a `unique_ptr` out of the two.

for exmaple :

```
auto ptr = CreateFile(/**/);
auto unique = toUniquePtr(ptr,&CloseHandle);
```

My implementation so far:

```
template <class T, class ClosingFunction>
struct CostumeDeleter {

    ClosingFunction closingFunction;

    CostumeDeleter(ClosingFunction closingFunction_) :
        closingFunction(closingFunction_) {}

    CostumeDeleter(const CostumeDeleter&) = default;
    CostumeDeleter(CostumeDeleter&&) = default;

    void operator() (T t) {
        closingFunction(t);
    }
};

template <class T, class F>
inline auto toUniquePtr(T t, F f) {
    CostumeDeleter<T, F> deleter(f);
    std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)> pointer(t, deleter);
    return std::move(pointer);
}
```

example use + compilation error*:

```
void* handle = malloc(100);
auto ptr = toUniquePtr(handle, &free);
```

The error I get from visual studio 2015 RTM 1:

```
Error   C2664   'std::unique_ptr<T,CostumeDeleter<T,F>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<T,CostumeDeleter<T,F>> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void *' to 'void *'
```

Which is weird. any help?

*no, I don't actually use `malloc` in my everyday work in C++, it's just for the example since its an easy function to replicate the compilation error.

Comment: is is calling the copy constructor for some reason. The copy constructor is deleted for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Didn't you mean `inline auto toUniquePtr(T* t, F f) {`, i.e., `T` is currently deduced as a pointer type

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki well, it shouldn't matter to the compiler anyway, and some resources aren't pointer types (SOCKET for example) and anyway, it didn't solve the compilation error..

Comment: @DavidHaim: It works for me if I make the change Piotr mentioned, and then also change `CostumeDeleter<T, F> deleter(f);` to `CostumeDeleter<T*, F> deleter(f);`

Comment: You can simplify your factory function body to just `return std::unique_ptr<T, CustomeDeleter<T, F>>(t, CustomeDeleter<T, F>(f));`

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, I initially used one-liner `make_unique` and as it failed, I tried different forms to make it work. currently I took your one-liner implementation. thanks you also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <class T, class F>
inline auto toUniquePtr(T t, F f)
```

Given the function template above, `T` is being deduced as `void *`. So `std::unique_ptr<T, decltype( deleter )>` expects to be passed a `T *`, aka `void **`.

To fix the error, change the template to

```
template <class T, class F>
inline auto toUniquePtr(T *t, F f)
//                      ^^^^
```

Similarly, change the deleter's `operator()` to accept a `T *`.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc810463093c5b90)

---

Another solution is to leave everything as you currently have it, and add the following alias to the deleter definition.

```
  using pointer = T;
```

Now, the `unique_ptr` will manage a `<deleter_type>::pointer`, i.e. `void *`, instead of `void **`, and your code will compile.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c650c534a3a999f0)

Comment: You beat me for a couple of seconds :(

Comment: I went with the `using pointer = T` since (as I commented) some of the resources are not pointers. it works beautifuly. thank you!

Comment: @DavidHaim The type that `unique_ptr` is managing is required to satisfy the requirements of a *NullablePointer*. That means that you can't use it manage a resource that cannot be compared to `nullptr`, for instance. But some stdlib implementations still allow you to do that. [This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443545bb28711275) is accepted by clang+libc++ and MSVC, the latter works because they compare the resource with a value initialized `unique_ptr::pointer`, which is `0` in this case. libstdc++ rejects it because they compare the resource with `nullptr`.

Comment: If you want to be portable, you'll need to wrap such resource types in some `Nullable<T>` template.